# Sorting function using recursion in Python

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

I have this this function `gensort` and `remAll`:

```
def gensort(L):
""" Sorts list L in ascending order
"""

if len(L) == 0:
    return 0
else:
    z = min(L)
    L = remAll(z, L)
    return [z] + gensort(L)


def remAll( e, L ):
""" Helper function for gensort(), removes all e in L.
"""
if len(L) == 0: 
    return L

elif L[0] != e:
    return L[0:1] + remAll(e,L[1:])
else:
    return      remAll(e,L[1:])
```

When I run `gensort`, I get an error

> can only concatenate list (not 'int') to list.

`remAll` works fine. If I try to create an empty list to add `z`, I get a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def gensort(L):
  if len(L) == 0:
    return 0       # <---- A
  else:
    z = min(L)
    L = remAll(z, L)
    return [z] + gensort(L)     # <---- B
```

In Line A, you are returning the number 0 if L is empty. So you will get `[z] + 0` in Line B after the recursive call, which is an error because you cannot add a list and number.

You should be returning an empty list, which you should write

```
    return []
```

for Line A.

Answer (score 0):

Your error stems from your base case check, where you `return 0`. Just return the empty list L.

If there's no special reason to use recursion in your removal function, might I suggest

```
def remAll(e, L):
    return [x for x in L if x != e]
```

Also a side note, this sorting method removes duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the base case of the recursion is returning `0` and not the empty list. Change the following code:

```
if len(L) == 0:   
    return 0
```

to

```
if len(L) == 0:   
    return []
```

and it should work.